# Edit List in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, list, edit, propertygrid

I have a `PropertyGrid` (winform) that contains a list of positions.

```
private ValuesCollection _position1 = new ValuesCollection();

public ValuesCollection Position1
{
   get { return _position1; }
   set
   {
     _position1 = value;
   }
}
```

ValuesCollection this class that I made with the following article: **[Customized display of collection data in a PropertyGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert)**

Each object in the list it belongs to class Values​​:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Values
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual double Value { get; set; }

    public Values()
        : this(null, 0)
    {

    }
    public Values(string name, double value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can not edit in the first level when the list opens because each item is an object.

[image]

I have to open another level (open the object itself) and edit there.

[image]

I want to edit in the first level and not open any object alone. I have not found a way to do it, does anyone have an idea?

(P.S. I do not want to use the `Collection Editor`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could implement a `TypeConverter` for your `Values` class

Comment: let me google that for you... http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/05/07/make-a-type-converter-to-let-the-propertygrid-display-and-edit-compound-properties-in-c.aspx